# How to know the CPU model like core i7-2600k in java?

Tags: java, model, system, cpu

I know how to get system info but i can not find the cpu model using System.getenv neither Runtime.getRuntime() nor SystemEnvironment.getSystemEnvironment();

how can i do it?

Comment: i'd be surprised if this hasn't already been answered....type this into a search engine: "java get cpu model"

Comment: its easy to not be surprised- actually do it. As of today, no results with relevant titles except for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in java using sigar API. 
Download sigar from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/files/), add `sigar.jar` and `sigar-x86-winnt.dll` to your buildpath.

You can get CPU details, for example CPU model using code like below:

```
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

public class CpuInfo {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SigarException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SigarException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo[] cpuInfoList = sigar.getCpuInfoList();

for(org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo info : cpuInfoList){
    System.out.println("CPU Model : "+info.getModel());
}
    }

}
```